# Cmake failed to link with Boost Regex in G++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

### Setup environment

**1. Install CMake**

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.14.5/cmake-3.14.5.tar.gz
tar xf cmake-3.14.5.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.14.5
./bootstrap --parallel=10
make -j4
sudo make -j4 install
```

**2. Install Boost**

```
cd ~
wget https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.69.0/source/boost_1_69_0.tar.gz
tar xf boost_1_69_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_69_0
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 ... cxxflags="-std=c++0x -stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" ...
sudo ./b2 toolset=gcc -j4 install
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
# Defines AppBase library target.
project(recipe_01)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS "ON")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

if(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD EQUAL 98 OR CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD LESS 14)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "app requires c++14 or newer")
elseif(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
endif()

find_package(Boost 1.60 REQUIRED COMPONENTS regex)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main Boost::regex)
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // output the available regex syntaxes
    std::cout
        << "Available regex syntaxes:\n"
        << "\t[0] Perl\n"
        << "\t[1] Perl case insensitive\n"
        << "\t[2] POSIX extended\n"
        << "\t[3] POSIX extended case insensitive\n"
        << "\t[4] POSIX basic\n"
        << "\t[5] POSIX basic case insensitive\n"
        << "Choose regex syntax: ";

    // correctly set up flags, according to the chosen syntax
    boost::regex::flag_type flag;
    switch (std::cin.get()) {
    case '0': flag = boost::regex::perl;
        break;

    case '1': flag = boost::regex::perl|boost::regex::icase;
        break;

    case '2': flag = boost::regex::extended;
        break;

    case '3': flag = boost::regex::extended|boost::regex::icase;
        break;

    case '4': flag = boost::regex::basic;
        break;

    case '5': flag = boost::regex::basic|boost::regex::icase;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Incorrect number of regex syntax. Exiting... \n";
        return -1;
    }
    // Disabling exceptions
    flag |= boost::regex::no_except;

    //requesting regex patterns in a loop
    // Restoring std::cin
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.clear();

    //Getting a String to match: in a loop
    std::string regex, str;
    do {
        std::cout << "Input regex: ";
        if (!std::getline(std::cin, regex) || regex.empty()) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Without `boost::regex::no_except`flag this
        // constructor may throw
        const boost::regex e(regex, flag);
        if (e.status()) {
            std::cout << "Incorrect regex pattern!\n";
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "String to match: ";
        while (std::getline(std::cin, str) && !str.empty()) {
            bool matched = boost::regex_match(str, e);
            std::cout << (matched ? "MATCH\n" : "DOES NOT MATCH\n");
            std::cout << "String to match: ";
        } // end of `while (std::getline(std::cin, str))`

        std::cout << '\n';

        // Restoring std::cin
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.clear();
    } while (1);

    return 0;
} // int main()
```

### To build

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

And I get this error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/main
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, 
boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISB_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SJ_RNS_13match_resultsISJ_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE[_ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISB_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SJ_RNS_13match_resultsISJ_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE]+0x8f): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106900::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j[_ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j]+0x2a): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, 
unsigned int)'
CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::re_detail_106900::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> 
> >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost16re_detail_10690012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC2ESC_SC_RNS_13match_resultsISC_SF_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSJ_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsESC_[_ZN5boost16re_detail_10690012perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEESaINS_9sub_matchISC_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC5ESC_SC_RNS_13match_resultsISC_SF_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSJ_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsESC_]+0x121): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106900::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target 'bin/main' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/main] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:72: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can not link to boost:regex with main function
Could you please tell me any solution for this issue?

I find some quote like

The boost 1.61 (and higher) are compiled with newer compilers, which use the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 .. heh ABI. Meaning that for -std=c++11 std::basic_string... becomes std::__cxx11::basic_string... (and likewise for std::list; see the gcc Dual ABI documentation).

Since your linker error claims there is a missing symbol that contains std::string (which is short for std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits,std::allocator>), you are either compiling with a compiler that is too old and uses ABI 0, or you are even compiling explicitly with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0.

But how can I fix in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
target_link_libraries(main Boost::regex)
```

to

```
target_link_libraries(main boost_regex)
```

And depending on your distro you may need to install some Boost devel packages.

Comment: It builds successfully
But when we run execute the file
`
./bin/main 
./bin/main: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_regex.so.1.69.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`
I think it is not root cause
Because when I run with thread
Using
`
find_package(Boost 1.60 REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system chrono)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main Boost::thread Boost::system Boost::chrono)
`
It is ok

Comment: @sun1211 Is libboost_regex.so.1.69.0 located in any of the paths in LD_LIBRARY_PATH? If not you should add the path to that shared lib so that your program can find it when you try to run it.

Comment: With thread or system or chrome
when I use `target_link_libraries(main Boost::thread Boost::system Boost::chrono)`
It is ok, Not need to be located in path like you
I think it is not a root cause

Comment: @sun1211 How about installing the boost regex development packages on your OS? You may need to do this even though you've built the boost library manually.

Comment: It is ok when installing Boost Regex
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Boost 1.60 found.
-- Found Boost components:
   regex
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done

Comment: @sun1211 You're still having issues? If not try installing the devel package, I'm not sure what operating system you're using, but if you're using CentOS for example you can install the following package for example https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/boost169-regex-1.69.0-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html. This will install the shared object file on your system.

Comment: Still having issue
Event I try to link to share library, It does not work